# tally score from database for a quiz

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have made a small online quiz for uni and have ran in to an issue which I have over come but want it to work with the data base instead of me hard coding the possible answers if anyone could help that would be great

```
 <?php 
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
include('cdb.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblas where id='$id';";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($results);

if(isset($_POST['idc'])) {
$idc = $_POST['idc'];
} else {
$idc = 1;
}
$idc++;

if ($idc >=6)
{
$idc = "1";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$try = $_POST['answer'] ;
}
?>
<br>
<?php
if ($idc >1 && $idc <6) 
{
echo "Question $id out of 4:<br />".$myrow['question'];
}

if($id > 0 && $id <5)
{
echo "<form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action = \"testttts.php?id=".$idc."\"/>";
echo "<select name=\"answer\">";
echo    "<option value= \"0\">----------SELECT ONE----------</option>
<option value=\"1\">".$myrow['A']."</option>
<option value=\"2\">".$myrow['B']."</option>
<option value=\"3\">".$myrow['C']."</option>
<option value=\"4\">".$myrow['D']."</option>";


echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"idc\" value=\"".$idc."\" />";
}
if($id >0 && $id <4)
{
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Continue\" />";
}

echo "</form>";

?>
<br><br>
<?php
If ($id == 4)
{
echo  "<form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action = \"testttts.php?id=1\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Finish\" />";
}
?>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<?php


if ($try == 5.55)
{ 
$_SESSION['tally'] ++;
} elseif ($try == 54.24)
{ 
$_SESSION['tally'] ++;
} elseif ($try == 6)
{
$_SESSION['tally'] ++;
} elseif ($try == 279.5)
{
$_SESSION['tally'] ++;
}



$tally=$_SESSION['tally'];
Echo "Test crap: <br>";
$try = $_REQUEST['answer'];
echo "$try <-- try";
$cor = $myrow['correct'];
echo "<br> $cor <-- correct";
echo "<br><br> tally --> $tally";
echo "<br> this is id: $id <br>";
$test=$_SESSION['test'];
$_SESSION['test'] ++ ;
Echo "session destroy $test <br>";



if ($id >=4)
{
session_destroy();
}
?>

<br><br><br><br><br>
```

I realize its very messy as it is a work in progress but if anyone could explain how I would get the data from the database to compare to the chosen answer that would be great.

thanks to anyone who can supply any help what so ever.

what the table looks like

```
 id|question | A   | B  | C  | D  | correct
 1 | ?????   | ??? | ???| ???| ???| 2
 2 | ?????   | ??? | ???| ???| ???| 1
 3 | ?????   | ??? | ???| ???| ???| 4
 4 | ?????   | ??? | ???| ???| ???| 4
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Can we forget about the PHP for now? Focus on the database.

Comment: I know how to do this with MYSQLI

Comment: the questions are the drop boxes, and what info on the database do you need and il post?

Comment: You need to be much clearer about what's in the table and what do you want the code to do.

Comment: i added the table to the question 
and what I am trying to do is to compare the chosen value which is in the drop box to the correct option in the table.